# MySQL - replacing specific character inside of column string

Tags: mysql

Got a column that keeps strings like such:

```
{"plan-36";"id-36";}
```

I want to check each string of this column, and if matches my criteria, it would change a specific character of this string (for example would change number `36` to `99`). Here's what i got so far:

```
SELECT string_column
FROM example_table
WHERE 
  INSTR(string_column,'plan-36') > 0
OR
  INSTR(string_column,'id-36') > 0
```

This only returns rows that has 'plan-36' or 'id-36' string in them. What i need is - if this row contain such strings, i need to change the `36` value, to let's say `99`.

Which sql functions do i need for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE example_table
SET string_column = REPLACE(string_column, "36", "99")
WHERE 
  INSTR(string_column,'plan-36') > 0
OR
  INSTR(string_column,'id-36') > 0
```

would be the syntax, this will update all instances of 36 to 99, Be careful and test on backup data first.

It may be better to use this

```
  SET string_column = REPLACE(string_column, "-36", "-99")
```

which includes the dash

Comment: @Edgar mark answer as correct if that is what you're looking for.